# I got error Recipient address required with Gmail API

Tags: node.js, gmail, buffer, gmail-api, rfc2822

I want to send an email with Gmail API.

Document say Gmail API require RFC2822 formatted and base64 encoded string.
So I write email contents and pass it to raw property.
But I got error: `Recipient address required.`

How can I fix this?

Here is my code.

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');
const {google} = require('googleapis');

// If modifying these scopes, delete token.json.
const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send'];
// The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
// created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
// time.
const TOKEN_PATH = 'token.json';

// Load client secrets from a local file.
fs.readFile('credentials.json', (err, content) => {
  if (err) return console.log('Error loading client secret file:', err);
  // Authorize a client with credentials, then call the Gmail API.
  authorize(JSON.parse(content), sendGmail);
});

/**
 * Create an OAuth2 client with the given credentials, and then execute the
 * given callback function.
 * @param {Object} credentials The authorization client credentials.
 * @param {function} callback The callback to call with the authorized client.
 */
function authorize(credentials, callback) {
  const {client_secret, client_id, redirect_uris} = credentials.installed;
  const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
      client_id, client_secret, redirect_uris[0]);

  // Check if we have previously stored a token.
  fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, (err, token) => {
    if (err) return getNewToken(oAuth2Client, callback);
    oAuth2Client.setCredentials(JSON.parse(token));
    callback(oAuth2Client);
  });
}

/**
 * Get and store new token after prompting for user authorization, and then
 * execute the given callback with the authorized OAuth2 client.
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} oAuth2Client The OAuth2 client to get token for.
 * @param {getEventsCallback} callback The callback for the authorized client.
 */
function getNewToken(oAuth2Client, callback) {
  const authUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    scope: SCOPES,
  });
  console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url:', authUrl);
  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
  });
  rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', (code) => {
    rl.close();
    oAuth2Client.getToken(code, (err, token) => {
      if (err) return console.error('Error retrieving access token', err);
      oAuth2Client.setCredentials(token);
      // Store the token to disk for later program executions
      fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token), (err) => {
        if (err) return console.error(err);
        console.log('Token stored to', TOKEN_PATH);
      });
      callback(oAuth2Client);
    });
  });
}

function sendGmail(auth){
  const makeBody = (params) => {
      params.subject = new Buffer.from(params.subject).toString("base64");
      const str = [
          'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"UTF-8\"\n',
          'MINE-Version: 1.0\n',
          'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n',
          `to: ${params.to} \n`,
          `from: ${params.from} \n`,
          `subject: =?UTF-8?B?${params.subject}?= \n\n`,
          params.message
      ].join(' ');
      return new Buffer.from(str).toString('base64').replace(/\+/g,'-').replace(/\//g,'_');
  }

  const messageBody = `
  this is a test message
  `;

  const raw = makeBody({
      to : 'foo@gmail.com',
      from : 'foo@gmail.com',
      subject : 'test title',
      message:messageBody
  });
jj

  const gmail = google.gmail({version:'v1',auth:auth});
  gmail.users.messages.send({
      userId:"me",
      resource:{
          raw:raw
      }
  }).then(res => {
    console.log(res);
  });
}
```

resulr:

```
Error: Recipient address required
```

edit :  show whole code. This code still get the same error.

This is almost Google's sample and I think bug is in my code.
I add sendGnail method and edit `authorize(JSON.parse(content), listLabels);` to `authorize(JSON.parse(content), sendGmail);` ,change SCOPES ,and delete listLabels method.
(listLabels method worked fine.)
After execute listLabels method, I change SCOPES and re-create token.json.
After get Labels, I change

Here is sample
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/nodejs?hl=ja

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this modification?

#### From:

```
].join(' ');
```

#### To:

```
].join('');
```

#### Note:

- I think that the script will work by above modification. But as one more modification point, how about modifying from `'Content-Type: text/plain; charaset=\"UTF-8\"\n',` to `'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"UTF-8\"\n',`?

If this was not the direct solution, I apologize.

### Edit:

I modified the function of `sendGmail` in your script.

#### Modified script:

```
function sendGmail(auth) {
  const makeBody = params => {
    params.subject = new Buffer.from(params.subject).toString("base64");
    const str = [
      'Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"\n',
      "MINE-Version: 1.0\n",
      "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n",
      `to: ${params.to} \n`,
      `from: ${params.from} \n`,
      `subject: =?UTF-8?B?${params.subject}?= \n\n`,
      params.message
    ].join(""); // <--- Modified
    return new Buffer.from(str)
      .toString("base64")
      .replace(/\+/g, "-")
      .replace(/\//g, "_");
  };

  const messageBody = `
  this is a test message
  `;

  const raw = makeBody({
    to: "foo@gmail.com",
    from: "foo@gmail.com",
    subject: "test title",
    message: messageBody
  });

  const gmail = google.gmail({ version: "v1", auth: auth });
  gmail.users.messages.send(
    {
      userId: "me",
      resource: {
        raw: raw
      }
    },
    (err, res) => { // Modified
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
      }
      console.log(res.data);
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: no.. it does not work... I call this function like this   
```js
// Load client secrets from a local file.
fs.readFile('credentials.json', (err, content) => {
  if (err) return console.log('Error loading client secret file:', err);
  // Authorize a client with credentials, then call the Gmail API.
  authorize(JSON.parse(content), sendGmail);
});
```  
Is this wrong?

Comment: @invalid Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. In my environment, I had already confirmed that your script worked fine by above modification. So I think that your next issue is different from the script of your question. From ``it does not work.`` and your script in your comment, I couldn't understand about your situation. So  can you provide whole script? Of course, please remove your personal information. If you can do, please add it to your question. By this I would like to confirm your next issue. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.

Comment: @invalid Thank you for updating your question. From your script, I modified the function of  ``sendGmail`` in your script. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: @invalid I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Comment: @Tanaike For the answer. It works flawlessly. I was trying the same mechanism using sdk but the error which SDK throws seems pretty general and constant.